# Need help comparing and displaying numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare my input with a list of numbers.

I put the print("2") in the code to see if what I did was correct, but I keep getting an error.

This is what I have so far:

```
list_a = [2,4,6,8,10,12]
number = input("Input a number:",)

def main(list_a,number):
    print("The Numbers in the list are:",list_a)
    for x in list_a:
        if number < x:
            print("2")

main(list_a, number)
```

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

```
list_a = [2,4,6,8,10,12]
number = int(input("Input a number:",))

def main(list_a,number):
    print("The Numbers in the list are:",list_a)
    for x in list_a:
        if number < x:
            print(x)

main(list_a, number)
```

The function `input` returns a string so you have to convert it using `int`.

Then we print `x` for each x in the list that is greater than our `number` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to achieve that is using list comprehension:

```
list_a = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
number = input("Input a number: ",)

def main(list_a, number):
    print("The numbers in the list are: ", list_a)
    greater_than_x = [x for x in list_a if x > int(number)]  # this is a list comprehension
    for y in greater_than_x:  # we print out all numbers that are greater than number
        print(y)

main(list_a, number)
```

**Output example:**

```
>>> number = input("Input a number: ",)
Input a number: 6
>>> main(list_a, number)
('The numbers in the list are: ', [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12])
8
10
12
```